# Multiplication/Division across different columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that is unfortunately blown up a bit and I want to perform multiplication and division between columns. These operations need to be performed in subsets within the table (in my example below groupbed by year and country) so I feel like groupby would be the solution.

| Year | Country | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | EU | 3 | nan |
| 2019 | EU | nan | 5 |
| 2022 | China | 1.5 | nan |
| 2022 | China | nan | 7.9 |
| 2022 | EU | nan | 5 |
| 2022 | EU | 0.4 | nan |

Simply put I want have a new column col[C] = col[A]/col[B] so that 3/5 & 1.5/7.9 & 0.4/5 and the same thing with multiplication in a fourth column.
The table can not be restructured unfortunately and I am not familiar enough with Pandas. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate with `groupby.first` and `merge`:

```
out = df.merge(df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'])
                 .first()
                 .eval('A/B')
                 .reset_index(name='C')
              )
```

output:

```
   Year Country    A    B         C
0  2019      EU  3.0  NaN  0.600000
1  2019      EU  NaN  5.0  0.600000
2  2022   China  1.5  NaN  0.189873
3  2022   China  NaN  7.9  0.189873
4  2022      EU  NaN  5.0  0.080000
5  2022      EU  0.4  NaN  0.080000
```